# Biblatex is putting brackets for APA citations instead of the expected (Author, Year) citations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am attempting to cite a website using biblatex in APA format.

However, it is citing it wrong i.e. an in-text citation looks like the following `[1]` instead of `(Author, Year)`

The same goes for the bibliography there should be no `[1]`. It should look like this:

`Inc. How to Conduct Competitive Research. May 2010. URL : https://www.inc.com/guides/2010/05/conducting-competitive-research.
html.`

Instead of like this:

`[1] Inc. How to Conduct Competitive Research. May 2010. URL : https://www.inc.com/guides/2010/05/conducting-competitive-research.
html.`

This is how my .tex file is set up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend = biber, hyperref,backref = true style=apa]
{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]
{LetterHead.png}}}%
}
\begin{document}
Some text that I am citing \autocite{Inc:2010:Online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is how my .bib file is set up

```
@Online{Inc:2010:Online,
author = {Inc},
title = {How to Conduct Competitive Research},
month = {May},
year = {2010},
url = {https://www.inc.com/guides/2010/05/conducting-competitive-
research.html}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

- You have a comma missing in your `biblatex` options.
- You need to load `babel` to use the `apa` biblatex style.
- You should load `hyperref` last in the package loading order; you don't need to add `hyperref` as a `biblatex` option.
- It's preferable to use numbers for the `Date` field if you are using `biblatex` (i.e., `5` instead of `May`)
- The `times` package is deprecated. You should use the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages instead.

I've removed irrelevant packages and code from you example and included your sample `.bib` item using `filecontents` to make the document self-contained.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{Inc:2010:Online,
author = {Inc},
title = {How to Conduct Competitive Research},
month = {5},
year = {2010},
url = {https://www.inc.com/guides/2010/05/conducting-competitive-research.html}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend = biber, backref = true, style=apa]
{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text that I am citing \autocite{Inc:2010:Online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! You are awesome! I just started using latex so I am getting use to the formatting. Why did some examples leave `babel` out? Thank you for the advice for using numbers for a date (is there a reason for this)? Lastly, how do you find out if packages that are outdated is `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` times new roman packages?